# Making MVC templates available in a Class Library (VS 2017)

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2017, umbraco, class-library

I have an Umbraco Cloud project I am working on in Visual Studio. Umbraco Cloud provides a script that creates a Visual Studio solution consisting of two projects: An MVC website containing the CMS' files, and a Class Library for the developer's own MVC code. The Class Library project contains a Controllers and a Models folder.

The problem I am having is that Visual Studio's MVC templates are not available from within the Class Library project. When I choose Add > New Item, I get many templates under "Visual C# Items" the Installed list, but nothing for MVC.

I understand that these templates are not needed to create MVC code, but they are helpful for me, and their absence is an inconvenience.

How can I make Visual Studio's MVC templates available in this Class Library project? I looked through this site for solutions, but came up with nothing. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
David

Comment: So if I'm correct, it creates basically two projects under one solution? if so, couldn't you do something like:
Pseudo code:
using ClassLibraryProject.Models.SuckMyModel ?

Comment: Jaberwocky, yes, it creates two projects under one solution. The problem isn't that they're not linked with each other (they are, and that's working fine). The problem is that the Class Library project is used to contain the site's .NET MVC code, but the MVC templates aren't available from within that project.

Comment: I haven't seen any of the code or how the Cloud builds your solution, but can't you just delete the other project and work with your own custom models on the Umbraco project?

Also, did you try what I said before? I mean I've done a lot of separate projects where one has some logic and custom models (like domain models for database logic blah blah) and I never seemed to have a problem linking them together by doing something like I said before. I mean, if I'm thinking it the wrong way, please let me know.